# makepasswd not working properly in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, openssl, random

I am using `makepasswd` to generate a bunch of random passwords in a VM.

After the upgrade to Stretch/Debian 9, the script either generates one or two passwords, and stops, or none at all.

It seems to take quite a (good) while to generate another password again.

First time calling it:

```
makepasswd
ndmBXpfp3
```

It generates immediately a random string as expected.

Second time:

```
makepasswd
```

And it keeps there waiting...and waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative solution, instead of modifying makepasswd sources, is installing the daemon `haveged` to speed up the key generation process. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install haveged
```

After installing it, `makepasswd` works as it should too.

The `haveged` daemon is now required in VMs and iOTs (e.g. raspberry) where the entropy is *normally* low.

From Debian, `man haveged`:

> NAME
>          `haveged` - Generate random numbers and feed Linux's random device.
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          `haveged`  generates  an unpredictable stream of random numbers harvested
>          from the indirect effects of hardware events on hidden processor  state
>          (caches,  branch  predictors, memory translation tables, etc) using the
>          HAVEGE (HArdware Volatile Entropy Gathering and  Expansion)  algorithm.
>          The  algorithm operates in user space, no special privilege is required
>          for file system access to the output stream.
>
> Linux  pools  randomness  for  distribution  by  the  `/dev/random` and
>          `/dev/urandom`  device interfaces. The standard mechanisms of filling the
>          `/dev/random` pool may not be sufficient to meet demand on  systems  with
>          high needs or limited user interaction. In those circumstances, `haveged`
>          may be run as a privileged daemon to fill the `/dev/random` pool whenever
>          the supply of random bits in `/dev/random` falls below the low water mark
>          of the device.

Answer (score 6):

It seems `makepasswd` was changed from using an openssl API to generate (pseudo)random numbers, to nowadays using an API based in `/dev/random`.

The problem is VMs and iOTs (may) have low activity and do not generate enough entropy to satisfy the script/`makepasswd` drinking from `/dev/random`

While I tried to find an option for it to drink random numbers from `/dev/urandom`, it has none.

So I just got an old version of `makepasswd`, as it is a perl script, and pointed the script to `/opt/bin/makepasswd` on my system ; and the script is now working as usual generating the +100 passwords I need in seconds.

As it can be seen from the source:

New `makepasswd`:

```
 my $buf = $RNG->bytes($bytes);
```

Old `makepasswd`:

```
 my $buf = Crypt::OpenSSL::Random::random_pseudo_bytes($bytes);
```

Interestingly enough, the data and version near the copyright has not been changed, which put me off track for a while.

In both of them:

```
$Program        = 'makepasswd';
$Version        = '1.10';
$Author         = 'Rob Levin <levin@openproject.net>';
$Date           = "Monday, 7 April 1999 at 22:56 (UCT)";
$Copyright      = '1997-1999';
```

However, from `changelog.Debian.gz`

```
Convert from Crypt::OpenSSL::Random to Bytes::Random::Secure (closes:
#792535).

 -- Colin Watson <cjwatson@debian.org>  Thu, 16 Jul 2015 11:45:20 +0100
```

Comment: It would be worth filing a bug about this; the change was made for licensing reasons, not cryptographic ones, and I think setting `NonBlocking` would be acceptable (so it uses `/dev/urandom` — see [Myths about `/dev/urandom`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) for useful background).

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt , concise and useful comments as always.

Comment: Hi @StephenKitt , ended up installing `haveged`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Why taking out all the Stretch tags? If that, the tags description also have to be edited, as they advise putting debian and the codename of the distro in questions together.

Comment: See [This criquet needs help!](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/this-criquet-needs-help) and [Do we need version specific tags for distributions?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/do-we-need-version-specific-tags-for-distributions). The idea is to get rid of those tags altogether; the [tag:debian] tag doesn't mention them, so there's no need to edit any tag description.

Comment: @StephenKitt was not aware of those threads. Actually it is the specific distro tags that advise including the debian tag too, thing which I have done.

Comment: I know: so users starting from [tag:debian] aren't pointed towards the release-specific tags, and once the latter tags disappear, there won't be any documentation issue.